# Syntax error in when trying to run a tornado main.py

Tags: python, tornado

This is my simple tornado project main.py file:

```
import os
import os.path
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.options
from tornado.options import options


class Index(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.write('Hello')

url_patterns = {
    (r'/', Index),
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(
        url_patterns,debug=True,
        cookie_secret="*****",
        xsrf_cookies= False,
        template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
        static_path= os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),

    )

    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(8080)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

When I want to run this file an error says that:

```
File "main.py", line 16
    (r'/', Index),
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I want to run this on centos 6 and python 2.7.8. This is a picture of my error:

[image]

What's wrong with my project?

Comment: I'm not seeing a syntax problem here (although it is late ...).  What version of python are you using?

Comment: @mgilson Most probably Python 2.6 or earlier: http://codepad.org/ZUkcm9r0. The `{}` syntax for set was backported to Python 2.7 only.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- Yes, that was what I was assuming when I couldn't find a syntax problem.  A quick google search showed that set literals showed up in python2.7 -- It sure feels like I've been using them for a long time now though . . .

Comment: Note that the `repr` output for sets is still the old in Python 2.7 as well: https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#other-language-changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're on python2.6 as everything *seems* to be valid syntax for python2.7.  On python2.7,

```
url_patterns = {
    (r'/', Index),
}
```

will *try* to construct a set with a single member which is a 2-tuple.  However, it will fail with a `TypeError` if `Index` isn't hashable.  Set literals didn't exist until python2.7 though, so for earlier python versions, your code will throw a `SyntaxError`.

Generally though, in my experience (with `webapp2`), the order of your handlers matters -- So you're better off using an ordered iterable rather than a `set`.  Possibly a `tuple` or a `list`.  e.g.:

```
url_patterns = [
    (r'/', Index),
]
```

And obviously if `tornado.web.Application` requires one or the other, use that ;-)  ([The docs show a list being used](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html), so that's probably safe...)

Comment: Yes, url_patterns should be a list.  Any iterable will work, but order matters so a frozenset isn't a good idea (and non-frozen sets usually won't work because your handler classes aren't hashable).

Answer (score 3):

The curly braces `{ }` you're using mean you're trying to define either a dictionary or a set. I assume `url_patterns`, like its counterpart in Django, is a tuple, so you'll need to use parentheses `( )` instead:

```
url_patterns = (
    (r'/', Index),
)
```

Comment: But -- Does that really explain a *SyntaxError*?  It seems that `{(r'/', 'whatever')}` _is_ valid syntax (at least in python2.7.  It's a set with a tuple as it's only member -- Of course, at run-time it'll raise `TypeError` if `Index` isn't hashable, but it can't know that before trying to run it AFAICS ...

Comment: @mgilson it gives a Syntax error on Python 2.6 (and I'd assume earlier), at least on my Mac